# Sign in with mongo shell without having my password shown?

Tags: security, authentication, mongodb

How can I sign into the `mongo` shell without showing my password? Everything says to either use

```
mongo -u user -p password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

or

```
mongo
> use admin;
> db.auth('user', 'password')
```

I don't like either one. The first leaves a command in cmd's history. The second isn't in the history but it still displays on screen in plain text. I tried only specifying a user in hopes I'd get a password prompt that doesn't display characters as I type, but in both cases an error occurs.

Is there a way to sign into MongoDB in a way that doesn't put my password on the screen or store it in an insecure file (like a .bat or anything)?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open feature request (as of 2.6).  For voting/tracking purposes see [SERVER-3788](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-3788).

The only way I can think of to achieve what you ask at present is to not use user/pass (i.e. [MONGODB-CR](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#mongodb-cr-authentication)) at all. If you instead use [X509 certs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/authentication/#x-509-certificate-authentication) to authenticate (new in 2.6 and requires an SSL enabled build) then you will no longer have the issue of plain text display and your instances will be more secure in general. It's something of a hammer to crack a walnut, but until the feature request is complete it is the only real option available if this is a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is an approach you can use from the command line which won't echo your password: specify the `-p` or `--password` parameter without providing a password. In this case you will be prompted to enter a password.

For example:

```
# Short parameter form
mongo -u user -p --authenticationDatabase admin

# Long parameter form
mongo --username user --password --authenticationDatabase admin
```

The shell output will look similar to:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.11
Enter password: %
```

I tested this as far back as MongoDB 2.4 (which reached end of life in March, 2016).